# Show that $M_m \neq 0$ for $m = (x, y - 1)$ where $A=k[x,y]$ and $M=k[x,y]/(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

> Let $A = k[x, y]$ for a field $k$ and let $M$ be the $A$-module $k[x, y]/(x)$. Given a maximal ideal $m$ in $A$, we write $M_m$ for the localization of $M$ at $m$.

> Show that
>
> 1. $M_m=0$ for $m=(x-1,y)$ and
> 2. $M_m \neq 0$ for $m = (x, y - 1)$.

Facts: $M=k[x, y]/(x) \cong k[y]$, and $M_m=S^{-1}M$.

Why is the localization $M_m$ given with $S=A-m$ and not $S=M-m$? In A&M (page 38) it defines the $S^{-1}A$-module as $S^{-1}M$ with $M$ an A-module in place of the ring A.

For Q1:

$S=A-m=k[x,y]-(x-1, y)$. Any ideal contains $0$ and the only $Ann_m(s)$, $s \in S$  is elements of $k$, but $k$ is a field.
Also we have the fact:
"Some properties of the localization $R^* = S^{−1}R =$ {$0$} if and only if $S$ contains $0$" from wikipedia.
Since $0 \notin S$ how can $M_m=0$? These elements are in the localization $\frac{1}{a}, \frac{1}{x}, \frac{y}{x} \in S^{-1}M = M_m$

For Q2:
$S=A-m=k[x,y]-(x, y-1)$. Again $0$ is in $m$ and $k$ is a field, and $k[y]$ is a field extension with no zero-divisors - is that enough to say that $M_m \neq 0$? E.g. $1, y, y^2 \in S$ so $\frac{1}{y} \in S^{-1}M = M_m$

edit: replace $S^{-1}M$ for $S^{-1}A$ in Q1

Comment: $S^{-1}M$ is not a ring, it's a module, so you can't invoke Wiki here. For computing $S^{-1}M$ you have to know that in the case $M=A/I$ we have $S^{-1}(A/I)\simeq S^{-1}A/S^{-1}I$, and in our particular case $I=(x)$ has the property that $I\cap S\neq\emptyset$, so $S^{-1}I=S^{1}A$, hence the quotient is zero. (I'm referring to Q1.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes,,that clarified Q1! So Q2 follows from I∩S=∅

Comment: One other thing: $M_{\mathfrak m}$ is not given by $S = M \setminus \mathfrak m$ simply because $\mathfrak m \subset A$, not $\subset M$.